# SQL, how to make view using a table by transform rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

please I need your help.
I am trying to make a view in SQL, first if I have this table:

[image]

How can I make a view using select to and the view will give me the table like this:

[image]

and here the ID will be auto increment.

I hope it's clear. I am sorry but I tried a lot to solve this and I really need it so please guys help me.

Thank a lot for every things

Answer (score 0):

You want to pivot the data, in a way.  You can use conditional aggregation along with `row_number()`:

```
select seqnum,
       max(case when po = 'A' then po end) as a,
       max(case when po = 'B' then po end) as b,
       max(case when po = 'C' then po end) as c,
       max(case when po = 'D' then po end) as d,
       max(case when po = 'E' then po end) as e
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by po order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

I will say that repeating the same values in the columns seems a bit strange.

Comment: Can i use this answer in a view?